# Facebook login does not work after iOS build

Tags: facebook, flutter, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, crashlytics

In my flutter app, I have facebook sign in integrated via Firebase authentication.

I also have different environments for Dev and Prod.

This works perfectly well on Android, and on my Debug-prod mode for iOS. However, when I build and publish to Testflight the app crashes for Facebook login and below is the error as seen on Firebase Crashlytics:

```
fb is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist
```

Seems quite straight-forward. However, I do have the URL scheme mentioned on my Release-prod.xcconfig and included that in my info.plist (As noted above, this works OK when in Debug mode)

Release-prod.xcconfig:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"

FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME=fbxxxxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

DISPLAY_NAME=AppName
```

Info.plist(relevant sections):

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxx---xxx---</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
</array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>$(FACEBOOK_APP_ID)</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

Other points to note, if relevant: I codesign automatically using Xcode and not using any CI/CD tool yet

I would expect it to work seamlessly after the build as well. Where am I going wrong? Please do help

Answer (score 1):

As I later figured out "Archive" setting of my Scheme was pointing to incorrect xcconfig.

I changed this to Release-prod and it worked